# Executing scp command from expect script - use of eof

Tags: expect, scp

I'm trying to create an expect script to perform and scp command to copy a given file to a remote machine.
If I run the following script, the scp command fails.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set ip_addr [lindex $argv 0]
set in_fname [lindex $argv 1]
set out_fname [lindex $argv 2]
set user [lindex $argv 3]
set password [lindex $argv 4]
set timeout 2

if {[llength $argv] != 5} {
  send_user "Usage: ./scp_copy.sh <ip_address> <in_fname> <out_fname> <user> <password>\n"
  exit 1
}

spawn scp $in_fname $user@$ip_addr:$out_fname

expect {
    (yes/no)  {send "yes\r"}
    timeout
}

expect {
    timeout
    {
        send_user "FAILED TO PERFORM SCP CMD.\n";
        exit 1
    }
    password:
    {
        send "$password\r"
    }
    eof
}
```

... however, if I remove the 'eof' at the end of the second expect clause and instead create a new expect clause at the end, the scp command works.

```
expect eof
```

Please can someone explain this. I'm completely new to expect (and bash) scripts and would be grateful for a simple explanation that helps me understand.

What does 'expect eof' do exactly? Does eof indicate that the spawned process has complete? If so, should I introduce another timeout e.g.

```
expect {
    timeout { exit }
    eof
}
```

What is the difference between the eof being inside the second expect clause and it's own separate expect clause? I was expecting the same effect.

Do I need to call 'close' at the end of an expect script?

Thanks.

Comment: without `expect eof` at the end, the script would exit immediately after the 2nd `expect {}` block which in turn would kill (with `SIGHUP`) the spawned scp process.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I appreciate that the without 'expect eof' at the end of the script, the script will complete and the scp command will fail. This is the reason for my question "What does eof do exactly?" I'm new to bash and expect, and so was hoping to understand this statement.

Comment: `eof` means end-of-file which means a file is closed. When expect spawns a process on a pty, expect is connecting the pty's master side and the process on the slave side. Usually when the process exits it'll close the pty slave side and expect will know that.